# Android as WiFi adapter?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

How do I use my phone's USB hotspot to transfer my WiFi network connected to my phone to my laptop? Is it possible? I'm running CyanogenMod 12.1 on my Galaxy Note II. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you please explain a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

- Plug your phone into your laptop
- On your phone, go to settings
- In the wireless & networks area, more -> Tethering & portable hotspot
- Enable USB tethering

Comment: Already tried. Connected to WiFi on phone, used official Samsung cable, turned on USB tethering and it didn't work. The computer did detect my ethernet however can't ping.

Comment: That's strange. Do you have access to another computer or another phone to try it with?

Comment: No I don't. But what I do know is, if I have 3G/4G on my phone, the USB tethering would work well

Comment: From what it says here http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00032109/ it would appear that Samsung devices can only tether mobile data, not WiFi.

Comment: What if I'm using CyanogenMod? And I'm running a Note II, International version to be exact.

Comment: It seems that cyanogen mod also has a USB tethering issue. Some people suggested enabling USB debugging, but if that doesn't work then I can't help you any more!